# 2012 trade shows we should be interested in

Tags: discussion, conferences

There's a nice calendar at http://www.1001noisycameras.com/2011/12/trade-show-calendar.html. We should try to send people to some of them.

Comment: We should also have some resources pulled together for members that will be at some of these anyway.

Comment: (The above question as I started it is sort of a placeholder. Can someone maybe flesh it out a bit?)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a great idea! Check out [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/) that describes how our conference attendance sponsorships work.

You can also take a look at sample sponsorship requests from [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/gamescom-2011-sponsorship-proposal) and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/software-craftsmanship-north-america-2011-sponsorship-proposal).

If there is a person or persons keen on attending an event, we can talk about whether we can support them and this site.